# e.stopPropagation(); in a custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Description :**

Following Code works as it should

```
$("body").on("click","#grumpy",function(e){

// perform some thing

 e.stopPropagation();

});
```

but if I create a custom function and if I want to `stopPropagation()` in that it does not work.. e.g

```
function myFunction()
{
   // do some work

 e.stopPropagation();
}
```

**MY CODE**

```
echo '<div class="recent_notice_in_side shake" id = "notice_no_'.$notice_id.'" onclick = "notice_expand(this.id)">
// other divs...

</div>';
```

how can achieve  `e.stopPropagation();` in a custom function I have searched Google but couldn't find how to do this in custom functions.

Comment: `myFunction` should have an event parameter named `e`

Comment: both of them won't work... `$("body").on("click","#grumpy",function(){` should be `$("body").on("click","#grumpy",function(e){`

Comment: I am sorry it was a typing mistake ... but can you tell me how to do this in a custom function

Comment: There's no such thing as a custom function. The only difference between your two cases is whether the function is named or anonymous. You should define them the same way.

Comment: in the named function when I click on the div it expands and when I click any where on the body except the div it contracts back to its original size .. this was going well till I started to have many divs so I made a named function and now nothing works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your named function needs to take a parameter `e`, just like the anonymous function does:

```
function myFunction(e) {
    // do some work
    e.stopPropagation();
}

$("body").on("click", "#grumpy", myFunction);
```

Comment: Alternatively (if some other code also needs to be run), you pass the event forward `$("body").on("click", "#grumpy", function (e) { doSomethingElse(); myFunction(e)});`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a click event of yours and passing in the 'e' to your function in the actual click event.

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "click" );
 myFunction( e );
```

Usage of created event can be handled in jquery itself. Below code demonstrates the same :

```
$(function () {
      var myFunction = function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      };
      $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
          var e = jQuery.Event("click");
          myFunction(e);
      });
```

in HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Stop Propagation" />
```

Comment: i have made a edit where a button click event fires and actually calls another method where e is passed, pls check and let me know if it works now